# sample spawned processes is alive and exit code

Tags: linux, bash, continuous-integration, sh

I have bash script that runs a long running process that prints a lot of stuff to stdout. I made the script print the process output only after it finished and only if it failed.

My problem is that some CI require **some** stdout prints every X minutes and the process sometimes take a lot more than those X minutes.

I'm trying to think of bash solution that would:

1. run the process and keep the stdout aside.
2. while the process is running, print "." to stdout every X seconds - to signal that the script is still running.
3. After the process is done, will be able to get its exit code and recat accordingly.

Here's is what I started writing:

```
run_process > output.txt 2>&1 & my_pid=$!
exited=0
while [ ${exited} -eq 0 ]
do
  timeout wait 5s ${my_pid};exit_code=$?;exited=1
  echo .
done
```

clearly, that doesn't work since timeout cannot get a series of commands.
Do you have other solutions?

Comment: What is `& mypid=$?`  I'm assuming you are missing a semicolon or newline?

Comment: It should be `mypid=$!`.  `$!` returns the pid of the last process put into the background.

Comment: Also, I think `-nq` should be `-eq`.

Comment: you are right... I'll edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
run_process > output.txt 2>&1 & my_pid=$!
while ps -p $my_pid > /dev/null; do
  echo -n .
  sleep 5
done
```

Get exit value from `wait`:

```
wait $mypid
echo $?
```

Comment: thanks! but I need a solution that combines them both :-) (wait for a process while printing dots, and then getting the exit code)

Comment: If the child process has already stopped, `wait` will return immediately with the exit code of the child process.

Comment: I loop through the pids on the wait part, and echo pid and exit code so you know which failed.